# Kibana 7.6.0 from windows and elasticsearch 8.1.0 from linux

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have my kibana 7.6.0 installed in windows and elasticsearch 8.1.0 in Linux. The versions are different. Will it actually work? I have to connect kibana from local to remote ES which is there in Linux server. can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Will it actually work?`

According to [product compatibility](https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix), Kibana and Elasticsearch version should be on the same level. It's OK that they runs on different platforms.

Comment: Ok got it... Thanks a lot for clearing my doubt!!!